# What tool can I use to create a chart similar to Google analytics behavior flow?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dotnetcharting

I want to create a, basically, Google analytic behavior flow but with data from a log file. Any tool, c# or JavaScript will work

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic, but this type of chart is called a Sankey diagram (and you'll find a ton of Sankey chart generators via Google).

Comment: That led me down the right path and I ultimately used d3js. Thank you. Please write your comment as a response and I will mark it as the answer